# What are the partial derivatives of the function below?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, functions, partial-derivative

I want to compute the gradient of the loss function below for one training example $(t,\mathcal{C_t})$. $w_c$ and $w_t$ are vectors in $\mathbb{R}^d$. The $w_c$'s are not taken from the same matrix as $w_t$.

\begin{equation}
L(t,\mathcal{C_t}) = \sum_{c \in \mathcal{C}_t } \log \big(1+e^{-w_c \cdot w_t}\big) + \sum_{c \in \mathcal{C}_t^-} \log \big(1+e^{w_c \cdot w_t}\big)
\end{equation}

Here is what I have so far. The partial derivative of $\log \big(1+e^{-w_c \cdot w_t}\big)$ w.r.t. $w_c$ (i.e., holding $w_t$ constant) is:

\begin{equation}
 \frac{1}{1+e^{-w_c \cdot w_t}} \times -w_t e^{-w_c \cdot w_t} = \frac{-w_t}{e^{w_c \cdot w_t} +1}
\end{equation}

And, similarly, its partial derivative w.r.t $w_t$ is $\frac{-w_c}{e^{w_c \cdot w_t} +1}$.

We proceed similarly for the second term. In the end, we have:

$\nabla L_{w_c} = \sum_{c \in \mathcal{C}_t } \frac{-w_t}{e^{w_c \cdot w_t} +1} + \sum_{c \in \mathcal{C}_t^-} \frac{w_t}{e^{-w_c \cdot w_t} +1}$

and:

$\nabla L_{w_t} = \sum_{c \in \mathcal{C}_t } \frac{-w_c}{e^{w_c \cdot w_t} +1} + \sum_{c \in \mathcal{C}_t^-} \frac{w_c}{e^{-w_c \cdot w_t} +1}$

Is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you derivation is fine! I end up with the same expressions.

Comment: Thank you for your help +1. Your answer seems to imply that in the case of $w_c$, there is no summation? Could you please expand on that?

Comment: @Antoine Your derivation is ok. I've only used a compact notation. I add the final summation form.

Comment: sorry, you can't combine the two summations like that because the $w_c$'s are not taken from the same matrix depending on whether they belong to $\mathcal{C}_t$ or $\mathcal{C}_t^-$. I've edited the question.

Comment: @Antoine Ah ok sorry! I didn't cath that point at first. I edit again.

Comment: sorry, my bad again, it is $w_t$ and the $w_c$'s which are not taken from the same matrices. All the $w_c$'s come from the same matrix.